# Where is located the download done underlined checkmark

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-icons

I'm trying to use Android's own icons to represent the download progress and completion in a notification. I've already found the progress icon `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download`

However I cannot find the *download complete* icon highlighted in the attached image.

[image]

I know there is `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done`, but that is not the same icon, it is simply the download icon in static form.

Where can I find the icon indicated in the mentioned image? Preferably accessible like `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download`, however it wouldn't be a problem to import it into the project as well, although I've looked for it online and couldn't find a single one exactly like it.

Comment: IMO this is custom icon made by Chrome, So you may have to create custom one from designer.

Comment: @OmiK I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant as an Answer to my Question, not a comment to my question. If you go to the bottom of the page you can post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is `check-underline` icon so

```
right_click on drawable -> New -> Drawable Resource File
```

try below vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M21,5L9,17L3.5,11.5L4.91,10.09L9,14.17L19.59,3.59L21,5M3,21V19H21V21H3Z" />
</vector>
```

I found this [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

**UPDATE**

The icon you mentioned may be not in `Android Default Icon Set`,
so create custom one from designer.

Comment: That icon is not the same as the one in the image I showed. Yours is too thin, it's the wrong icon.

Comment: @Shadow IMO this is custom icon made by Chrome, So you may have to create custom one from designer.

Comment: @OmiK I believe you are correct, the download manager has the normal ".._done" icon that I mentioned. Do you want to reply to my question so I can pick your answer?